# glibc detected - double free or corruption (!prev)

Tags: c

I'm getting the error you may see in the title, and I can't figure out why.

The code:

```c
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

struct CData {
    int* num;
    char* adr;
    char* ph;

    void (*init)(CData* owner);
    void (*del)(CData* owner);
    char* (*getAdr)(CData* owner);
    void (*setAdr)(CData* owner, char* adr);
};

void CData_init(CData* owner) {
    owner->num = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    owner->adr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*255);
    owner->ph = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*255);
}

void CData_del(CData* owner) {
    free(owner->num);
    free(owner->adr);
    free(owner->ph);
}

char* CData_getAdr(CData* owner) {
    return owner->adr;
}

void CData_setAdr(CData* owner, char* adr) {
    owner->adr = adr;
}

int main() {
    CData* data = (CData*)malloc(sizeof(CData));

    data->init = CData_init;
    data->del = CData_del;
    data->getAdr = CData_getAdr;
    data->setAdr = CData_setAdr;

    data->init(data);

    data->setAdr(data, "asdasd");
    printf("%d", data->getAdr(data));

    data->del(data);

    free(data); 

    return 0;
}
```

So I think the error is caused by the char* manipulations but I don't know why.

What I want to do is I want it to be possible to pass a string as a parameter to `data->setAdr` and I want it to be assigned to the variable afterwards.

Compiling line:

```
gcc -o test main.cpp
```

Comment: "double free" - that should tell you something, maybe something like "double `free()`"

Comment: You're not allowed to free string literals. (And you're leaking the previous value in `setAdr`.)

Comment: Yeah I made such a guess at first, but where?

Comment: How do I free the memory then? And should I?

Comment: Why are you using C++ compiler for C code?

Comment: There is little point in having an `int *` in a structure if you only allocate one `int` for it.

Comment: How do I compile c with gcc then?

Comment: @ohyou - rename the file to `main.c`.

Comment: Rename the file to `main.c` and change the includes from `<cxxx>` to `<xxx.h>`

Comment: this function: 
void CData_setAdr(CData* owner, char* adr) {
    owner->adr = adr; is overlaying the pointer that was the result of the malloc in the CData_init() function.  The desired operation would be: strcpy( owner->adr, adr );  Also, the malloc'd memory should be initialized to all '\0' so all strings will be properly terminated without having to calculate/set the appropriate byte in the set... functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data->setAdr(data, "asdasd");` is problematic.

You are setting the address of a memory block that is not allocated by malloc and later trying to free it with `free`. Freeing such memory blocks (not allocated by malloc) except NULL pointer lead to undefined behavior.

This is also leaking atleast 255 bytes of memory in your case. [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html) can help you understand better in this case.

Changing following function should fix this (Rename it appropriately)

```
void CData_setAdr(CData* owner, char* adr) {
    strcpy(owner->adr, adr);  /* include cstring */
}
```

Comment: So in my case I need to simply store a pointer to a static string and care not about the memory allocation?

Comment: In that case, you should not give ownership of string to `CData` and setter should allocate and free strings. You can not mix allocation and free rules across modules. To enable both way of setting, you need slightly more framework to detect when to free and when not to free.

Comment: Did you mean `strcpy` instead of `strcmp`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
data->setAdr(data, "asdasd");
```

Your implementation is :

```
void CData_setAdr(CData* owner, char* adr) {
    owner->adr = adr;
}
```

So, you overwrite the address of a previously-`malloc()`ed memory with a pointer to a constant string, so when you do `data->del(data);`, `glibc` warns that you are freeing memory that was not allocated, plus the previously allocated memory is lost. Try instead:

```
void CData_setAdr(CData* owner, char* adr) {
    strcpy(owner->adr, adr);
}
```

Remember to add suitable error-checking, etc!